# Apache HTTP Server mod_session_dbd Session ID Reuse Vulnerability

Tags: apache, security, pci-compliance

I have scanned my website on TrustWave for PCI Compliance and foud this error

```
Apache HTTP Server mod_session_dbd Session ID Reuse Vulnerability
```

My website is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise on Apache Server 2.4.4(On XAMPP)

Following link is the Patch to fix this issue but unable to locate the location of the file to edit

```
 http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/session/mod_session_dbd.c?r1=1409170&r2=1488158&diff_format=h
```

as suggested by http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-2249

Can any one guide me please !

Best regards !

Comment: this is the lastest version of http_apache 2.4.6 is vulnerable so you have nothing to upgrade ...

Comment: so how can i overcome with this issue?

Comment: check my answer to know exactly what is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this vulnerability is on the `lastest` `version` of `apache` so there is nothing to `upgrade`

if you have installed this version of apache on `redHat-Enterprise (version:4 or 5 or 6)` so your are not `affected`

if no :

this vulneravility is about `session_start(); $_session();` whene session_id is set by the php there is no `session_expired` that renew the `session_id`

```
Solution:
```

dont use this module `session_start();` and wait fot he new update of the `apache` that's all and there is nothing to Carry about

Comment: @vanurag yes really and you can use it without carry too , but if you know that your server is populated for cracking and hacking (Commercial usage) dont use this module and use `setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue");` in the place of `session_start();`